# Specifying new Maven repository

Tags: maven

Good day!

I've specified in my project's pom.xml file a new repository. So before  tags I've added this configuration

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
        <id>maven-db-plugin-repo</id>
        <name>maven db plugin repository</name>
        <url>http://maven-db-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/maven/repo</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

like indicated [here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-db-plugin/)
But, when i'm trying to execute `mvn db:update`, I'm getting this error:

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'db' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/andriy/.m2/repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Any suggestions of what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

**Update**

I've also added this dependence

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>com.googlecode</groupId> 
  <artifactId>maven-db-plugin</artifactId> 
  <version>1.3</version> 
  <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

And still getting those warnings:

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.googlecode:maven-db-plugin:jar:1.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for com.googlecode:maven-db-plugin:1.3: Plugin com.googlecode:maven-db-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.googlecode:maven-db-plugin:jar:1.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adding a repo isn't enough to make a plugin work. You have to configure the plugin in your pom, too. There's an example of configuring the maven-db-plugin at the bottom of the [project's home page](http://code.google.com/p/maven-db-plugin/).

The maven-sql-plugin has [better documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/). If it fits your needs, you might just use that instead.

Comment: Posted maven-db-plugin configuration after </repositories> tag and still have same error. Maybe I'm putting it into wrong place?

Comment: The [pom reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html) shows where everything belongs in a pom, [including plugins](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins).

Comment: I'm sorry about too many questions, but now I'm very new in maven. I've also added this dependence `<dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-db-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>`
And still getting those warnings:`[WARNING] The POM for com.googlecode:maven-db-plugin:jar:1.3 is missing, no dependency information available [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for com.googlecode:maven-db-plugin:1.3: Plugin com.googlecode:maven-db-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Fai...`

Comment: Don't ask a new question in a comment. Just start a new question.

Comment: Or, if the you're still having the same problem as your original question, then update your question with the new details.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to have the following configuration:

```
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>maven-db-plugin-repo</id>
      <name>maven db plugin repository</name>
      <url>http://maven-db-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/maven/repo</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </pluginRepository>
```