# Unable to use maven-database-plugin (Googlecode)

Tags: maven-plugin

I have pretty much the same problem posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297553/specifying-new-maven-repository), and tried out the things mentioned, but getting same error.

```
...        
    <repository>
        <id>maven-db-plugin-repo</id>
        <name>maven db plugin repository</name>
        <url>http://maven-db-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/maven/repo</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>

...
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven-db-plugin-repo</id>
        <name>maven db plugin repository</name>
        <url>http://maven-db-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/maven/repo</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-db-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <type>jar</type>

                     <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <configuration>
                        <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                        <url>${database.url}</url>
                        <username>${database.username}</username>
                        <password>${database.password}</password>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>create-schema</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>execute</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                                <!--<url>jdbc:postgresql://${database.server.host}:${database.server.port}:${database.name}</url>-->
                                <srcFiles>
                                    <srcFile>src/main/sql/schema.sql</srcFile>
                                </srcFiles>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
```

My task is to insert seed data in DB. As I can't reply on top of that thread as per StackOverflow recommendations, I am posting this new question. Please help.

Thanks